# Associative arrays python soap client

Tags: php, python, soap

I am new to python coding .I have done a soap client program in php but now i want to convert it in python

I am stuck at this point

```
$result = $client->GetLastData(array('Id' => array($id)));
```

How can i convert this set of code from php to python.
Can any one please tell me is there an way to pass an  associative arrays in python

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi this answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495950/how-to-implement-associative-array-not-dictionary-in-python
(possible duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special you really have to do. If you have an associative array like this (In Python called a dictionary):

```
a = {
    "id": [1234567, 55555, 4444444]
}
```

And you want to pass your dictionary (associative array) the way you are trying to do in your example, you just need to do this:

```
GetLastData(a)
```

If you are looking to pass specific data from your associative array / dictionary, then you can do this:

```
GetLastData(a.get("id"))
```

or

```
GetLastData(a["id"])
```

I would suggest using get as the default return will be None if the "id" key is not found. If you access with the "square brackets", it would throw a `key error`, and you would have to handle accordingly.